# (Gensim)Python : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mycorpus.txt'

Tags: python, error-handling, gensim, corpus

I am currently going through **Gensim** tutorial on **Corpora and Vector Spaces** in that I am right now trying to understand  [**Corpus Streaming – One Document at a Time**](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#corpus-streaming-one-document-at-a-time).

After I compiled these lines of codes referring the above link in python3:

```
class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open('mycorpus.txt'):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by whitespace
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split())

corpus_memory_friendly = MyCorpus()  # doesn't load the corpus into memory!

print(corpus_memory_friendly)

for vector in corpus_memory_friendly:  # load one vector into memory at a time
    print(vector)
```

I am getting this error:

```
<__main__.MyCorpus object at 0x7f2e37e17d68>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    for vector in corpus_memory_friendly:  # load one vector into memory at a time
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 3, in __iter__
    for line in open('mycorpus.txt'):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mycorpus.txt'
```

I have already downloaded ***mycorpus.txt*** still I am getting this error. Where should I store mycorpus.txt file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the paths to both your Python script and `mycorpus.txt`?

Comment: @Tagc I have stored the mycorpus.txt file in desktop and I am using IDLE3 in ubuntu to compile it ....does that help?

Comment: @Tagc more specifically its stored at /home/aniruddh/mycorpus.txt

Comment: @Tagc u there mate

Comment: Try placing `mycorpus.txt` in the same directory as the Python script

Comment: @Tagc how do i find out in which directory my Python script is

Comment: Within IDLE you should see it if you go to `File` -> `Recent Files`

Comment: @Tagc i am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS where should i search in that

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever figure out how to fix this?